# How I can access to these values in body question,

Tags: php, arrays

How I can fetch the values of "callback_data" of theses arrays for telegram bot  when I click the inline button query

```
stdClass Object
(
    [inline_keyboard] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [text] => btn1
                            [callback_data] => v
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [text] => btn2
                            [callback_data] => r
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `stdClass` objects in your array, properties of which are accessed with arrow notation (`->`).

`$yourVariable->inline_keyboard[0][0]->callback_data`

`$yourVariable->inline_keyboard[0][1]->callback_data`

Comment: I did check now